# What approach to use to detect violations of media ethics in news?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, nlp

I've been trying to come up with a solution to detect violations of media ethics in news articles. For example, I need to detect if an article has mentioned the name of a victim of rape. So far, I've tried to perform a binary classification using a Multinomial Naive Bayes classifier with sklearn. However, it does not produce very accurate results and I believe this is because there are no clear-cut features to be used for classifying. I really appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction or give me some tips on how to proceed.

Comment: I think this is a very hard problem to solve, and I am not sure you will get any answers with practical advice, despite it being an interesting goal.

Comment: @NeilSlater I think the same. It seems my only option is to use NLP and pattern matching.